# Solve for only certain variables with symbolic solver

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I am trying to solve a system of equations in MATLAB with 3 variables and 5 constants.  Is it possible to solve for the three variables with solve while keeping the constants as symbolic and not replacing them with numerical values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use the [SOLVE](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/symbolic/solve.html) function (from the [Symbolic Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/symbolic/)) you can specify the variables you want to solve for. For example, let's say you have three equations with variables `x`, `y`, and `z` and constants `a` and `b`. The following will give you a structure `S` with fields `'x'`, `'y'`, and `'z'` containing symbolic equations for those variables which include the constants `a` and `b`:

```
>> S = solve('x+y=a','x-y=b','z=x^2+y^2','x','y','z');  %# Solve for x, y, and z
>> [S.x; S.y; S.z]  %# Get the equations from the structure

ans =

     a/2 + b/2  %# Equation for x
     a/2 - b/2  %# Equation for y
 a^2/2 + b^2/2  %# Equation for z
```

If symbolic solutions *can't* be found for a system of equations, numeric solutions will be returned instead.

Comment: Yes. It's also a good idea to note that this will only work if the OP has the MATLAB Symbolic Toolbox installed and that the variables need to be declared as symbolic using the `syms` commmand.

Comment: @Gilead: You don't actually have to declare the variables as symbolic if the equations and variables passed to SOLVE are strings, like in the example I used above.