# Solving a set of equations to obtain a function in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am solving a set of equations in Matlab but my variables are functions. The code is given below:

```
syms p0(s) p1(s) p2(s) a1 a2 b1 b2;
eqn1=s*p0-1==-a1*p0-a2*p0+b1*p1+b2*p2;
eqn2=s*p1==a1*p0-b1*p1;
eqn3=s*p2==a2*p0-b2*p2;
```

I want to obtain `p0`, `p1` and `p2` in terms of `s`. How do I solve it?

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/solve.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Solve for only certain variables with symbolic solver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605071/solve-for-only-certain-variables-with-symbolic-solver)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments you can use `solve` to get a solution to a system of algebraic equations.

```
S=solve('s*p0-1=-a1*p0-a2*p0+b1*p1+b2*p2','s*p1=a1*p0-b1*p1',' s*p2=a2*p0-b2*p2','p0','p1','p2');
[S.p0; S.p1; S.p2]
```